# kvm guest host get ip by dhcp failed when cloudflare-warp on open

Tags: cloudflare, kvm, dhcp, libvirt, warp

My English level is not high, please forgive!Thank you so much!
I searched a lot of information but couldn't find the answer.

question:
after cloudflare-warp connect，kvm guest host get ip by dhcp failed,as show below:
system info:
LMDE5(Linux Mint Debian Edition)
cloudflare-warp 2023.10.120-1
libvirtd (libvirt) 7.0.0
error info:
warp-cli connect
in guest kvm:
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
…
No DHCPOFFERS received.

warp-cli disconnect
in guest kvm:
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPOFFER of 172.20.0.3 from 172.20.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 172.20.0.3 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 172.20.0.3 from 172.20.0.1
bound to 172.20.0.3 – renew in 1525 seconds.

try:

1. mark "0x100cf" on guest host's ip by iptables command
   2.delete "172.0.0.0/12 dev CloudflareWARP proto static scope link" in cloudflare-warp's route
   not solved

expecting:
When cloudflare-warp is turned on, kvm host can obtain the ip normally